# Should we return [postal-code] to sender?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [postal-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postal-code) tag has 394 questions. Most of the questions are in relation to postal/zip/postcodes that are used in the physical addressing of post or mail.

The questions fall under some general headings:

1. Regex type questions. Asking to match/find certain characters within a string

   - [Having difficulty in pattern matching Postal Codes for an oracle regexp_like command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73722581/9606612)
   - [Regex to identify postcode that includes comma](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72965880/9606612)
   - [Extract postal codes from global addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72701086/9606612)
   - [How to make sure a string postal code follows the 6 character letter digit, letter digit, letter digit, pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70357467/9606612)
   - [Get list of address dont have UK address mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63630915/9606612)
   - [Validating the postcode so it can only start with LS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30463361/9606612)
2. Non programming questions. Some asking for postcode files.

   - [Does it exist some kind of alliance or group of software development actors involved with postal services?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71649703/9606612)
   - [Download FSA map of Canada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71312257/9606612)
   - [OS Data Hub - Postcode from Grid Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66634251/9606612)
   - [Matching postcode to index of deprivation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62281861/9606612)
   - [How to track a shipment which i am sending it from Germany to India?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59644052/9606612)
   - [Where to get worldwide City name, State/Province name, Postal/Zip code, Country, Latitude, Longitude data for free](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51766003/9606612)
   - [Postal (Zip) Code database / Address validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48543367/9606612)
   - [Can there be a postal code area which falls on to multiple time zones?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47796795/9606612)
   - [Adding specific shipping costs in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46698193/9606612)
   - [Blank space in UK postal code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46692277/9606612)
   - [Searching for postal code map of Germany for R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45751476/9606612)

Questions in bucket one generally have a specific software or tool mentioned and sometimes also have [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).

Questions in bucket 2 might not be on-topic for Stack Overflow, but could be on-topic for https://gis.stackexchange.com/

The [street-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/street-address) tag with 556 questions also exists as a tag covering the physical addressing of post or mail. While [zipcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipcode) with 432 questions also exists and as a minimum should be a synonym of [postal-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postal-code), if not burninated in its own right.

The [postal-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postal-code), [street-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/street-address) and [zipcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipcode), don't add any specific nuance to the questions being asked.

I believe the tag [postal-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postal-code) should be burninated.

It fails some of the preliminary checks before burnination:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

**Yes**, it is describing postal codes that are used for the addressing of postal mail. The tag isn't related to programming, but some of the actions users are wanting to undertake such as [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) of a postcode are related to programming.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

**No**. It doesn't have any relation to programming at all! This is about geography!

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

**No**. This tag isn't even about a programming concept! The posts normally include tags for the problems users are facing e.g. [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

**No** In the case of the questions, it could mean many different things, postcode, zip code, postal code or any of the other country specific address identifiers that exist

It is also problematic because:

The tag is country specific ([With the solid compound being popular in many English-speaking countries and also being the standard term in the Netherlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code)), with other tags such as [postal-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postal-code), [street-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/street-address) and [zipcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zipcode) which also exist and cover similar concepts of [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and other programming concepts.

Comment: *"Most of the questions are in relation to postal/zip/postcodes that are used in the physical addressing of post or mail."* Then it seems like a perfectly valid, well-defined tag, being used appropriately. Arguably, yes, [postal-code] and [zipcode] should be merged.

Comment: @CodyGray [they are different aren't they?](https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-zip-code-and-postal-code.html)

Comment: @RobertLongson I believe that ZIP codes are a specific type of postal code, despite that site's insistence that they are not.  More reputable sources than keydifferences.com, such as the Universal Postal Union (found via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code), which agrees), [define ZIP codes as a type of postal code](https://www.upu.int/UPU/media/upu/documents/PostCode/General-Addressing-Issues.pdf).

Comment: They're the same thing, @Robert. More specifically, they are different terms for the same thing that are used in different regions of the world. Much like "county" and "parish". I don't think the regional distinction is especially useful to capture in a tag.

Comment: That said, it's at least not obvious that [zipcode] and [postal-code] should be merged, since there are unique aspects to ZIP codes that aren't common to all postal codes (e.g., ZIP+4).  That may be true of other specific types of postal codes, but I'm not sure.  On the other hand, it could be the case that that differentiation between types of postal codes in the tags is unhelpful, and we'd be better off with a single tag.  One would need to look at how they're being used to know.

Comment: @CodyGray if someone asked me to implement a zip code validator I'd be looking at the United States postal system, if they asked me for a postal code validator I'd be looking at the UK postal system and I wouldn't expect to have the same regex. The concept, as you say is the same though.

Comment: the problem is there are lots of different variations of the concept of a postal code, wikipedia identifies at least 11 different variations (CAP, CEP, Eircode, NPA, PIN, PLZ, Postal code, Postcode, Postal index, PSČ, ZIP Code), do we need a tag for each? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_code

Comment: @A.Steer Those variations are just how the concept is called in different languages. Since SO is english only I think we can safely ignore them.

Comment: @BillTürstandswithUkraine Eircode is used in Ireland which is a predominantly English speaking country and has a different address format than UK postcodes, so shouldn't that have its own tag as per your thinking? My point of bring those variations up, is that while SO is English speaking, if I was asked to create a validation of Irish postcodes, I would use a different design that I would for UK or American. The English speaking world is wider than those two countries and postal codes are different formats in these countries, shouldn't the tag be country agnostic?

Comment: "Then it seems like a perfectly valid, well-defined tag, being used appropriately." Is this for real? Would it be appropriate to have, say, a [tag:surname] tag as well?

Comment: linked question in relation to other geographical tags - ["\[country\] road, take me home"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420968/9606612)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Do surnames have formatting rules?

Comment: @Cerbrus Some systems seem to believe so. My real last name has two capital letters in it and a lot of systems can't seem to spell it correctly...

Comment: @HereticMonkey My point is that postal codes have very specific rules. Surnames don't, and systems that do have rules for surnames are just implemented poorly... Something not having a format is not taggable...