# "[country] roads, take me home"

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/country) tag is quite ambiguous and isn't really on topic for this site, and has no synonyms. And it has racked up 400+ questions!

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   Sort of. It's **very** ambiguous; it can mean country codes, country names, coordinates etc., all of which aren't really related to programming.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   No. It doesn't have **any** relation to programming at all! This is about geography! What's this tag doing on a programming site :D
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   No. This tag isn't even about a programming concept! The post should include tags about e.g. what they are using like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), or the thing that they are facing problems with e.g. [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array).
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No! In the case of the questions, it could mean many different things, country codes, country names, geographical coordinates etc.

Shall we take [country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/country) home?

Comment: Various related on-topic tags/concepts that this could be replaced with, where relevant: [tag:locale], [tag:country-codes], [tag:geolocation]

Comment: Also [any question tagged \[country\] \[flags\]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcountry%5D+%5Bflags%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=1) is also misusing the [tag:flags] tag.

Comment: "No [country] for old tags"

Comment: "[country] road, take me home"

Comment: Linked question in relation to other geographic item tags - [Should we return \[postal-code\] to sender?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420912/9606612)

Comment: For us culturally challenged: *[Take Me Home, Country Roads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_Me_Home%2C_Country_Roads)*. [A version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vrEljMfXYo).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I may be culturally challenged (towards American culture anyway), but Country Roads is still embedded in my soul thanks to quite a lot of modern media :) Heck it was the best thing about the Fallout 76 trailer.