# Should [sender] be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag [sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sender) has 328 questions and many of them seem to not follow the tag guidance.

The tag is:

- ambiguous as sender could mean anything even in the context of events
- not strictly programming related as this is just a generic term that describes the sending party
- the tag does not add any meaningful information to the question
- it could be on-topic but it depends on context

What should it be replaced with? Should it maybe be merged into a better tag?

Comment: In my opinion it makes no sense and I think it should be removed. The 328 questions should have the tag replaced with ones that fit them better.

Comment: Could replace it with something along the lines of event-sender to clarify its intended use, though in most cases this tag is not needed and can just be removed without hurting question quality, so maybe we don't really need to replace it or merge it at all, just burn it

Comment: Let's return this tag to its [sender]

Comment: I thought I had seen this before. Turns out I was thinking of [Return this \[delivery\] to sender](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297165/11107541) and [Should we return \[postal-code\] to sender?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420912/11107541)

Comment: The concept of `sender` as described in the current tag wiki seems reasonably well-defined, it would just need a lot of cleanup effort… [A lot of them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsender%5D+*mail) could just be retagged to [[tag:mail-sender]]

Comment: @Bergi while well-defined, does it add anything to post meaning? Could you imagine any question that's asking specifically about this name? It it is a historical question (when was it used first, how the name was chosen) or comparison question (e.g. what other languages do use this), it is off-topic. If it asks about events in those languages, does "sender" *conventional* name really add something meaningful to the post? Can anyone be expert in "conventional name of ... used in..."? I'd argue you can't be expert in `self` conventional name in `python`, and this is even more niche...

Comment: Augh. Actually [tag:self] looks also like a trash bin, collecting distinct questions with very little in common, most of which do not ask about `self` properties... (and its wiki mentions "keyword", which is true for e.g. rust, but fundamentally wrong for Python)

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444104/akka-java-sender-method-behaves-strangely) seems like a fine usage example, asking about the sender of an event in an actor framework - I think it adds something there. I might agree that correct usage is a bit niche, but that doesn't make it a bad tag.

Comment: The [sender] is sending wrong message to the community...